# Remove page numbers on blank pages after title page and table of contents in book document class?

Tags: books

I'm exploring the book document class and tried the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
This is my title page.
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter%
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter%
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-10] % chktex 8
\end{document}
```

This generates two blank pages. The first blank page is after the title page, and has a page number "2". The second blank page is after the table of contents, and has the page number "ii" and the heading of "CONTENTS".

What's the proper way to get rid of these?

Comment: If you want an empty page after the title you could append `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}` in `titlepage`. If you want to remove page numbers from all empty pages, look at this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512723/easily-remove-page-numbers-for-blank-pages-book-class

Answer (score 1):

Try this, flipping between pagestyles.

```
% pagenosprob.tex  SE 633684

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
This is my title page.
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter%
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-10] % chktex 8
\end{document}
```